# Conservation of angular momentum in LSZ reduction formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, s-matrix-theory

I recently solved a problem involving calculating an LSZ reduction formula for the decay of a polarized photon into two pions. Specifically, I wrote an expression for the matrix element $\langle p_+,p_-;\mathrm{out}|p_\gamma,\alpha;\mathrm{in}\rangle$ (representing a photon of momentum $p_\gamma$ and polarization vector $\mathbf{e}_\alpha$ decaying into two pions of momenta $p_+$ and $p_-$) in terms of field operators for a Maxwell field and a complex scalar field acting on vacuum states.

The polarization $\alpha$ encodes the angular momentum of the incomoing photon. **Within an LSZ formula, how can we enforce that the outgoing states created have the same net angular momentum as the incoming photon?** There do not seem to be any terms in the LSZ formula that can be used to ensure that the matrix element disappears when the conserved charge for angular momentum, $$L^{\nu\lambda}=\int\mathrm{d}^3x\,(T^{0\nu}x^\lambda-T^{0\lambda}x^\nu),$$ where $T$ is the energy-momentum tensor, is not the same for the initial and final states. There also does not seem to be any convolution between the pions' creation operators and the polarization vector in the LSZ formula.

Since this is based on a homework problem, I am not including the relevant LSZ formula, but it is very similar to the standard expressions given in most textbooks. The PSE post [LSZ and current conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309337) implies that the conservation laws may be implied by the exponential factors. Here, the LSZ formula includes the exponential factor $\exp \mathrm{i}(-p_+y_1+p_-y_2)$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are integrated over, and the zeroth components of $p_\pm$ are $|\mathbf{p}_\pm|^2+m^2$; this does not immediately suggest the required conservation law.